# share features in Laravel

Tags: laravel, web-applications, share

I'm new to Laravel here and currently, I'm working on a developing web app which needs has the features to be able to share to other social media platform. did few types of research and try some techniques (packages by `jorenvh`) but it didn't quite work as I'm pretty not sure myself. can anyone teach me some examples?

when trying the `jorenvh packages` on dummy project it  works perfectly but when I tried to combine them with my project, it says `$socialShare is undefined`

**controller**

```
 public function nasilemak() {
        $socialShare = \Share::page('https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-custom-foreign-key-name-example','Learnt to cook Nasi Lemak',)
            ->facebook()
            ->twitter()
            ->whatsapp()
            ->telegram();
        return view('malaysian.nasilemak', compact ('socialShare'));
    }
```

Comment: in my blade 
<h2 class="font-bold underline font-serif text-center">Social Media:
</h2>{!! $socialShare !!}<br>

Answer (score 1):

Make sure import Facade

```
use Jorenvh\Share\ShareFacade as Share;
```

and then you can do

```
 public function nasilemak() {

        $socialShare = Share::page('https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-custom-foreign-key-name-example','Learnt to cook Nasi Lemak',)
            ->facebook()
            ->twitter()
            ->whatsapp()
            ->telegram();;
    
         return view('malaysian.nasilemak', compact ('socialShare'));
    }
```

if still not working then clear cache

```
php artisan view:clear

php artisan route:clear

php artisan optimize

php artisan cache:clear
```

Also instead of html you can generate link also

```
 $socialShare = Share::page('https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-custom-foreign-key-name-example','Learnt to cook Nasi Lemak',)
            ->facebook()
            ->twitter()
            ->whatsapp()
            ->telegram()->getRawLinks();;
```

output will be

```
array:4 [▼
  "facebook" => "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-custom-foreign-key-name-example"
  "twitter" => "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Learnt+to+cook+Nasi+Lemak&url=https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-custom-foreign-key-name-example"
  "whatsapp" => "https://wa.me/?text=https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-custom-foreign-key-name-example"
  "telegram" => "https://telegram.me/share/url?url=https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-custom-foreign-key-name-example&text=Learnt+to+cook+Nasi+Lemak"
]
```